# Trying to get a field from a fetched entity in rules

Tags: rules

I'm trying to use PHP evaluation in rules, and I'm having some trouble getting the data.

This is the beginning of the variable $entity_fetched:

```
Test 103
stdClass Object
(
[vid] => 611
[uid] => 1
[title] => Test 103
[log] =>
[status] => 1
[comment] => 1
[promote] => 1
[sticky] => 0
[nid] => 611
[type] => calendar_event
[language] => und
[created] => 1380898459
[changed] => 1380898459
[tnid] => 0
[translate] => 0
[revision_timestamp] => 1380898459
[revision_uid] => 1
[body] => Array
(
)
[field_date_time] => Array
(
[und] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[value] => 1380898800
[value2] => 1380898800
[timezone] => America/Detroit
[timezone_db] => UTC
[date_type] => datestamp
```

I'm trying to get the value under field_date_time, but trying to get it as an array gives me an error that I am trying to get arrays from a stdClass object.

```
<?php print_r($entity_fetched['field_date_time']['und']['0']['value']); ?>
```

So then I try to do this:

```
<?php print_r($entity_fetched->field_date_time->und->0->value); ?>
```

and it gives me an error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I get this information?

Comment: Let me know if you are still facing issue in getting the required values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct way to get the value is:

```
<?php print_r($entity_fetched->field_date_time['und']['0']['value']); ?>
```

The `$entity_fetched` is returning an object so to access it values you would need to use `->` operator, and than you have array contents which you can access using the array subscript operator `[]`.

**Note:** You **cannot** access object members via the array subscript operator `[]`.
For accessing the object members you need to use the `->` operator.
And to access the array contents we use the `[]` operator.